# How to get image url of a post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pinterest

I am developing a Pinterest pinit plugin for Wordpress. Pinterest pinit buttons requires an image URL and post URL... how can I get an image URL?

I used the below code but it didn't work out:

```
$pid=get_the_ID();
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($pid);
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id);
echo $image_url[0];
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: currently you are getting the id of the featured image on the post.  Are you trying to get the featured image?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also tried this?

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this where $catposts is a post featured image query.

```
$category_id = 'your_category_id'; $NUMBEROFPOSTS = '4'; $catposts = get_posts('category='.$category_id."&order=DESC&numberposts=".$NUMBEROFPOSTS); 

foreach ($catposts as $item) :

     echo '<li class="active" style="height: 100px; width: 71px;">';

     echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( $item->ID ).'">';

     echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($item->ID)).'">';

     echo '</a>';

     echo '</li>';

endforeach;
```